# Killing a WPF application from a timer

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a System.Threading.Timer that is running to check whether a session is valid or not.  If the session of the WPF application is determined to be ended, from what could be an external source, I would like to shutdown the application.

When trying `Application.Current.Shutdown()` or a few other similar variations, I am getting exceptions because it is obviously trying to end the application from a thread that does not own it.  I am not sure the best way to handle this and looking for any similar implementations or thoughts anyone had.

Comment: I'm not sure on the specifics, but I think you have to `Invoke` a method on the main thread.

Comment: you could just kill the process from the timer if you're feeling rambunctious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => Application.Current.Shutdown()));
```

Comment: or simple `Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()`